# What constitutes "UI interactions" for AsyncTask?

Tags: android, user-interface, android-asynctask

[AsyncTask](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask) is a standard way to perform long running operations asynchronously on a background thread without holding up the UI thread.  One should not perform any UI interactions from the doInBackground() method.

My question: What are examples of UI interactions that are forbidden?  Would it be any of the following:

- LayoutInflater.inflate()
- View.findViewById()
- TextView.setText()

I'm inclined to say yes, but we have some code right now that does all of these (and more) and is called from the doInBackground() method, and yet the code is working.  I've seen other people indicate they receive an exception when attempting to perform UI activity from doInBackground(), but that is not our experience.

Our code is generating an on-screen report that is not visible until the entire operation is complete.  On rare occasion (hard to reproduce) when attempting to cancel the operation very quickly, we will see the application get into a weird state, but it doesn't crash.

Before changing our code in hopes of finding this rare condition, I wanted to see if anyone had some thoughts on why our code is "working" as-is.

The only other tidbit of information that might be helpful is that our doInBackground method has the following code template:

```
    protected Boolean doInBackground(Void... voids) {
        if (null == Looper.myLooper()) {
            Looper.prepare();
        }

        publishProgress(0.0);

        // Perform ui/non-ui logic here

        Looper myLooper = Looper.myLooper();
        if (null != myLooper && Looper.getMainLooper() != myLooper) {
            myLooper.quit();
        }
        return true;
    }
```

The Looper is needed for some of the report generating code (omitted) that uses a **new Handler()** to generate data.  I'm not sure if creating the Looper is somehow making our ui interactions legal.

(I do have a stack trace that clearly shows our UI activity being called from doInBackground, in case you thought we might be spinning off some separate threads to update our UI)

Comment: May I correct you. AsyncTask was designed to create short running background ops of up to 5 seconds. Beyond that you will probably hit an ANR. For long running ops use a service.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`AsyncTask` is not meant for really long running work, it should complete within a few seconds.  It is a one-shot completely managed thread context, which should not have its own `Looper` attached to it.  That actually will break the backing `AsyncTask` functionality - starving off other future `AsyncTask` operations you may be starting.  If you have something which requires a `Looper`, you should be using your own `Thread` or `ThreadPool` rather than an `AsyncTask`.  You'll also want to make sure you retain a reference to your `AsyncTask` so it can be cancelled appropriately - this is a source of many memory leaks and/or exceptions due to invalid state when `onPostExecute()` is called.

The intent of the `publishProgress()` method is to give your app the ability to get updates it can reflect on the UX.  You are correct, `setText()`, etc. should not be run in the `doInBackground()` callback.  That callback is executed in arbitrary thread context in which you do not control and cannot make UI updates.

You may be able to use `inflateLayout()` and `findViewById()`, but this is not a good practice to do this outside of initialization as these are potentially expensive operations.  Inflation has to parse the binary layout and create view objects on the fly.  Finding by ID walks the entire view hierarchy to find the component you desire.  A better practice would be to cache these at creation (for an `Activity` or `Fragment`) or when creating a view as part of an adapter (such as a `ViewHolder` in `RecyclerView`.

Comment: Ok, understood that AsyncTask might not be the best fit here and the fact that we need a Looper for other functionality is yet another indicator that some other approach might be better.  Despite these shortcomings, I'm still interested in knowing why this approach is even working with our current UI calls.

Comment: It really depends on what UI calls you mean.  The call to `setText()` should definitely throw an exception.  The `findViewById` and inflate will probably work ok.

Comment: Our code is using setText() and it is not throwing an exception.  This is my main question...why is it not throwing an exception if setText() is not allowed?

Comment: Is the `TextView` in question always setup (inflated) from the `AsyncTask`?  It is possible for `setText` or other UI operations to be called for a widget if it is done from the same thread in which it is created - though that's usually not a good practice to get into.

Comment: Yes, it is setup (inflated) from the doInBackground() method of the AsyncTask.  So perhaps we are saying that ui operations aren't allowed from the doInBackground() method because (usually) the ui components are first setup on the ui thread and then interacting with them later from another thread is what causes the exception?  Interesting theory!

Comment: That's exactly what I'm saying.  Most of the time your UI components are inflated / created in the main thread (UI thread) of the app.  The system restricts interactions with the UI components which alter what they display to be on the same thread used for their creation.  This is why when a bg thread (including `AsyncTask`) alters the UI component it throws an exception.  The same will actually hold true if you add a listener (think button) but the widget was created in a bg thread.  The listener should throw an exception as it is always run in the UI thread.